# Sympy get Symbol name

Tags: python, sympy, symbols

I can get the name of an "undefined" symbol:

```
import sympy as sym
knodef = sym.Symbol('k_{nodef}')
print(type(knodef))
sym.pprint(knodef.name)
    
<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
k_{nodef}
```

But as soon as I define it as an expression, I cannot get the name anymore.

```
kdef = sym.Symbol('k_{def}')
kdef = sym.tan(b*x)
print(type(kdef))
sym.pprint(kdef.name)      # AttributeError: 'tan' object has no attribute 'name'

tan
<Error raised>
```

**How can I get the name of kdef?**

Similarly for functions...

```
knodef2 = sym.Function('k_{nodef2}')
#display(disp.Math(knodef2.name), type(knodef2))
print(type(knodef2))
sym.pprint(knodef2.name)

<class 'sympy.core.function.UndefinedFunction'>
k_{nodef2}
```

... (is there in this case an equivalent to defining the Symbol)?

Comment: You redefined the variable `kdef`.  It is no longer a `Symbol`.  It is now the `tan` expression.  `sympy` operates within python, and `=` is a python operator, not a `sympy` one.

Comment: https://docs.sympy.org/1.5.1/gotchas.html#equals-signs

Comment: @hpaulj - So you mean that `kdef` lost all association with the string `'k_{def}'`, as if it were never declared?

Comment: Correct.  In python you don't declare variables.  You assign values to variables, and subsequent assignments overwrite earlier ones.  Variables are just ways of referring to objects.  After the 2nd assignment `kdef` refers to the `sympy.tan` object.

Comment: @hpaulj - Excellent! Thanks to your comments, I tinkered a bit, and learned something important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer based on comments by hpaulj and ulterior experimentation and learning...

Assigning `kdef = sym.Symbol('k_{def}')` assigns the name `'k_{def}'`, because that is an attribute of class `sym.Symbol`.

Later assigning `kdef = sym.tan(b*x)` simply defines a new object of class `sym.tan`, and uses `kdef` as a variable for it, but it actually has nothing to do with the previous object. So at this point, there is no more association between `kdef` and `'k_{def}'`.

This is easily seen with:

```
kdef = sym.Symbol('k_{def}')
print('kdef = ', kdef, ', address = ', hex(id(kdef)), sep='')
kdef = sym.tan(b*x)
print('kdef = ', kdef, ', address = ', hex(id(kdef)), sep='')

kdef = k_{def}, address = 0x20f21b58228
kdef = tan(b*x), address = 0x20f21b584f8
```

This even happens with assignments to the same type, where in principle the same exact memory block could be used:

```
q = 2.1
print('q = ', q, ', address = ', hex(id(q)), sep='')
q = 30000.1
print('q = ', q, ', address = ', hex(id(q)), sep='')

q = 2.1, address = 0x1c4dbd5d0d0
q = 30000.1, address = 0x1c4dbd5d2b0
```

Besides, it also turns out that class `sym.tan` has no `name`, so it is not possible to get it because it does not exist.
Since a given variable may or may not have a `name`, one could simply `try`/`expect`, or inquire with `dir()`.

Answer (score 6):

As you demonstrate, the `name` attribute of Symbol and Function can be used to return a string form of the "name". For UndefinedFunction you can use `.func.name` to get that string, but for defined FunctionClass you can just use `str` on the `func` attribute:

```
>>> s=Symbol('s');f=Function('f');a=f(s);b=tan(s)
>>> s.name
's'
>>> f.name
'f'
>>> a.func.name
'f'
>>> str(b.func)
'tan'
```